# How to stop horizontal scrolling of Sticky header of my application

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following shows the layout of my application: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rhgyLjvx/

It has app main header (red), sticky section header (dark blue), fixed footer (grey) and fixed left side nav (green). The application should have full scroll bars on both sides. And should scroll only the main section (yellow).

The vertical scroll happens as I want. But sticky section header (dark blue) horizontally scrolls with the section.

Is there any way to get the sticky header fixed to left and right sides and stop scrolling sideways?

I'm having another big problem. My whole application scrolls in devices including the fixed position divs. Please check in mobile emulator.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.Sticky')).forEach((stickyEl) => {
console.log("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& ", stickyEl)
 Stickyfill.add(stickyEl);
});
```

```css
#root, body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
    
    .app {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.main {
    padding-top: 70px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    min-height: 70px;
    max-height: 70px;
    background-color:red;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: fixed;
 z-index: 999; 
}
.sidenav {
  background-color:green;
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
 z-index: 999; 
}

.landing {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
}

.content {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
 background-color: grey;
}
.view {
    width: 100%;
   background-color: aqua;
}
.page-header {  
    
    background-color: #0c004a;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 999;   
    position: sticky;
    top: 70px;
    right: 0;
    left: 250px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.page-section {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    
    margin-bottom: 50px;
     background-color: purple;
}
.page-content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}

.page-panel {
    display: block;    
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    width: 75rem;
    min-height: 43.8rem;
}

.page-footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #979797;
    opacity: 1;    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 250px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="root">
      <div class="app">
        <header id="app-header" class="header"></header>
          <div class="main">
            <nav id="side-nav" class="sidenav"></nav>
            <div class="landing">
              <div class="content">
                <div id="adeb-maint" class="view">
                  <div class="Sticky page-header"></div>
                    <div class="page-section">
                    <div class="page-content">
                      <div class="page-panel" style="width: 75rem; min-height:       43.8rem;">
                        <label>Customer WWDSSD:</label>
                        <label style="margin-top: 750px;display: block;">Last Change  skdjskdq   :</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="page-footer">
                      <div class="actions-bar">
                        <button name="OK" class="ok">OK</button>
                        <button name="Cancel" class="cancel">Cancel</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stickyfill/2.0.3/stickyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Give me a moment to study your HTML as its quite messy on first glance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code Clean Up**
I have amended the HTML as it appeared to have a lot of nested DIVS that wasnt serving any purpose

There was also references to classes that was not in your CSS, the JavaScript (jQuery) wasnt serving any purpose what so ever (not for the content you have supplied us with)

**Preview Code** I have viewed the code in a larger preview window and works fine, you will need to alter the CSS to reflect the height you want.

```css
#root, body, html {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
header {
  background-color:red;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 70px;
  max-height: 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 2; 
}

.pro-main {
  padding-top: 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background-color:green;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 2; 
}

.pro-landing {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  background: #979797;
  padding: 5px;

}

.objectview {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.card-header {  
  background-color: #0c004a;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100% ;
  z-index: 5;
  border-top: 5px solid #979797;
}

.card-section {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}


.card-panel {
  display: block;    
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  padding-top: 50px;
  width: 75rem;
  min-height: 43.8rem;
}

.card-footer {
  background-color: #979797;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding-right: 1ex;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <header id="app-header" class="pro-header"></header>
<div class="pro-main">
    <nav id="side-nav"></nav>
    <div class="pro-landing">
      <div id="deb/m10mast/debtor-maint" class="objectview">
          
          <div class="card-section">
<div class="card-header"></div>
        <div class="card-panel" style="width: 75rem; min-height:       43.8rem;">
        

              <label>Customer WWDSSD:</label>
              <label style="margin-top: 750px;display: block;">Last Change  skdjskdq   :</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <div>
              <button name="OK" class="ok">OK</button>
              <button name="Cancel" class="cancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I can't use position: fixed, as 'card-header' has a variant height. So the 'card-panel' should push down accordingly.

Comment: I'm having another big problem. My whole application scrolls in devices in regards to the fixed position divs. Please check in mobile emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about CSS display: flex et al. [Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)

Or you can find an example [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Rmd3Rn8_hDNW1zSWRoXzBTclU)

The real bonus here is the page size and orientation changesare handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* You just need to update it like following */
 .card-panel
 {
position: absolute;
}
```

.card-header {

```
position: fixed;
top: 78px;
right: 0;
left: 254px;

}
```